# How to show a Voice Activity Indicator from a Web RTC Voice Engine audio channel in C++?

Tags: webrtc, openwebrtc

I want to show an indicator when i am receiving voice using the voice engine of web rtc.

I found a code sample of a VoiceActivityIndicator but the sample is dated . 2012 , and it do no more exists in web RTC current source code.

the information seems to be encoded as an Audio Frame Type.

Does some one knows how to retrieve this information using only the "voice engine" subset of webrtc from C++ ?

Does someone can point me toward some code samples that is doing this  with current webRTC source code?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? If yes, please share the answer.